# Create responsive top menu in angular or anything else (like Chrome uses with bookmarks bar when you resize the page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Can you direct me or give me some advice please on how to create a navigation bar (Angular 1, jQuery, css, etc) that behaves like Google Chrome bookmarks bar when the page is resized. Basically as the page size gets smaller a new button/symbol (>>) appears on the bar. Buttons from the right that cannot fit due to the smaller resolution move under the >> symbol. If you press the symbol a drop down appears with the hidden buttons. When the page reaches mobile resolution of course I will switch to mobile menu, but I need this step between the full menu and the mobile.

Google Chrome browser manages bookmarks bar view when you resize the page in a great way. If in Chrome you have a lot of bookmarks two arrows (>>) appear on the right side and when you make the window smaller more bookmarks hide under these arrows.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Making menu div `overflow:auto` would be simplest solution. Here's plunk for that
http://plnkr.co/edit/vAYTGgNnQtH1iE2vsIpS?p=preview

For your particular requirement, here is horizontal slider with arrows in the end to handle scroll
https://codepen.io/mahish/pen/RajmQw